# When is the automorphism group of a finite $p$-group nilpotent?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, automorphism-group, nilpotent-groups

Suppose $G$ is a finite $p$-group with odd $p$. Is it true, that $Aut(G)$ is nilpotent iff $G$ is cyclic?

When $G$ is cyclic, $Aut(G)$ is indeed abelian and thus nilpotent.

However, I do not know how to prove the statement that if $Aut(G)$ is nilpotent, then $G$ is cyclic. Nor do I possess any counterexamples.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: If $Aut(G)$ is nilpotent, $G$ need not be cyclic, see [here](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01220373).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The order of the automorphism group of ${\tt SmallGroup}(31,729)$ is $3^9$  and hence nilpotent.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps it might be noted that it has been proved that in a suitable sense [*the automorphism group of a finite $p$-group is almost always a $p$-group*](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0602039).

As for concrete examples, see for instance [this paper of mine](https://arxiv.org/abs/1406.7651) and the references therein.