# When is the automorphism group of a finite p-group abelian?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, automorphism-group

Suppose $G$ is a finite $p$-group with odd $p$. Is it true, that $Aut(G)$ is abelian iff $G$ is cyclic?

When $G$ is cyclic, $Aut(G)$ is indeed abelian.

However, I do not know how to prove the statement that if $Aut(G)$ is abelian, then $G$ is cyclic. Nor do I possess any counterexamples.

The answer to the similar question about nilpotent groups is negative:
[When is the automorphism group of a finite $p$-group nilpotent?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2925613/when-is-the-automorphism-group-of-a-finite-p-group-nilpotent)

Also, as any group with abelian automorphism group is metabelian, any $p$-group with abelian automorphism group is nilpotent of degree 2.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: There are nonabelian groups with abelian automorphism groups. See [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/9944/) A specific example is ${\mathtt{ SmallGroup}}(64,68)$, which has automorphism group elementary abelian of order $2^9$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Hom}[0]{\mathrm{Hom}}$$\newcommand{\Aut}[0]{\mathrm{Aut}}$$\newcommand{\Inn}[0]{\mathrm{Inn}}$As per your other question, the groups of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1406.7651) provide concrete examples of finite $p$-groups $G$ of nilpotence class $2$ such that $\Aut(G)$ is isomorphic to the additive group $\Hom(G/G', Z(G))$, and thus $\Aut(G)$ is abelian.

Note that if $G$ is a group such that $\Aut(G)$ is abelian, then so is $G/Z(G)$, as it is isomorphic to the subgroup $\Inn(G) \le \Aut(G)$ of the inner automorphisms of $G$. Thus $G$ is nilpotent, of nilpotence class at most $2$.

Comment: Could you please expand this answer so that it is more self-contained. What is the relevance of this "other" question, and what is in that paper.

Comment: @quid The question from [yesterday](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2925613/when-is-the-automorphism-group-of-a-finite-p-group-nilpotent).

Comment: @quid will edit as requested.